# How to incorporate delay into a jquery each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following function:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    var echoText = 'Hello world!';
    echoText = echoText.split('');
    $.each(echoText, function(key, value){
        $("#content").append(value);
    });
});
```

This simply echoes the input text. What I want to do, though, is to add a delay between every character echoed, so it looks like a slow human typing. Any ideas how to proceed? I tried googling, but nothing helps so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the `setTimeout()` function:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    var data = 'Hello world!';
    var lastIndex = 0;

    var fnEcho = function() {
        if (lastIndex < data.length) {
            $("#content").append(data[lastIndex]);
            lastIndex++;

            window.setTimeout(fnEcho, 1000);
        }
    }

    fnEcho();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

**Typewriter** plugin

look

http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/jquery-grab-bag/text-effects.html

use ike

```
$("#my-container").typewriter();
```

you can download from [Here](https://github.com/jaz303/jquery-grab-bag/blob/master/javascripts/jquery.text-effects.js)

```
 $.fn.typewriter = function() {
        this.each(function() {
            var $ele = $(this), str = $ele.text(), progress = 0;
            $ele.text('');
            var timer = setInterval(function() {
                $ele.text(str.substring(0, progress++) + (progress & 1 ? '_' : ''));
                if (progress >= str.length) clearInterval(timer);
            }, 100);
        });
        return this;
    };
```

Comment: @Demian -  Don't forget that 'reinventing the wheel' makes each time the wheel a bit more rounder!

Comment: @roXon I beg to differ! I've seen too many odd shaped reinvented wheels to agree...

Comment: @Ivar, ok, than use your preferred wheel (there are many... and your opinion can be subjective in some cases.) But be careful to choose the appropriate tire... rims... pressure... Or just reinvent the wheel. It might best suit your car ;D

Answer (score 0):

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    var echoText = 'Hello world!';
    var currentChar = 0;
    var intval = setInterval(function(){
        var value = echoText.charAt(currentChar);
        $("#content").append(value);
        currentChar++;
        if(currentChar >= echoText.length){
            clearInterval(intval);
        }
    }, 10);
});
```

I haven't tested it, so it might be buggy, but this is the way to do it. You can increase the value 10 to slow down the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  var echoText = 'Hello world!';
  echoText =echoText.split('');
  $.each(echoText, function(key, value){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#content").append(value);
    }, key * 1000);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var printNextChar = function(theStr, pos){
    pos = (typeof(pos) == 'undefined') ? 0 : pos;
    $('#content').append(theStr.substr(pos,1));
    ++pos;
    if(pos <= theStr.length){
        setTimeout(function(){printNextChar(theStr,(pos));},300);    
    }
}

$("document").ready(function(){
    var echoText = 'Hello world!';
    printNextChar(echoText);

});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Toukakoukan/nxCZr/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `$.animate` and `step`

```
function SimulateTyping(containerID, data) {
    var dv = $('#' + containerID), len = data.length;
    dv.text("");
    $({count: 0}).animate({count: len}, {
        duration: len * 15,
        step: function() {
            dv.text(data.substring(0, Math.round(this.count)));
        }
    });
}
```

Call it like

```
SimulateTyping("content", someText);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/JAxU9/